# Change default facebook text on stream.publish

Tags: facebook, publish

I want to be able to change the default text in the red square (Si noe om dette.. say something about this).

I have a webform where the user can enter text and submit it to a database. Upon submit I also want the user to be able to post this to facebook.
Now Im able to do this using stream.publish, but I can not add the the text written by the user. 
So this way the user has to reenter the webform text in the facebook share box.. 
Anyone know if there is a way around this?

[image]